# My combobox returns incorrect text value

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

```
 public void DD_Location()
    {
        var ctx = new LCCDB_EF();
        var query = ctx.tbl_Location;
        CB_Location.DataContext = query.ToList();
    }

    private void CB_Location_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
       textbox_test.Text =CB_Location.Text;
    }
```

Output in Textbox

> System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Location_5E43C6C196972BF0754973E48C9C941092D86818CD94005E9A759B70BF6E48E6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(null != CB_Location.SelectedItem)
    textbox_test.Text = CB_Location.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your XAML I can't be sure, but are you sure you've bound the list correctly? Try setting the Items property of combobox to your list, rather than the data context. Depending on what the type is and what you'd like to bind the text to, you may need to set the  DisplayMemberPath property as appropriate, too.